# Using getNext() with Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to do an autocompleter in mootools 1.11. Everything works fine but i just cant check if

```
this.selectel.getNext()
```

is null or whatever. Firebug outputs [li] for every element and  [null] for the non existing element i output via getNext();

I saw that some people are just doing:

```
if(this.selectel.getNext()) {...
```

but thats not working here because i always get the null object. Something terribly stupid must be going on here...

Here comes some code around the problem:

```
this.selectel = $$('ul.results').getFirst();

...

onCommand: function(e, mouse) {
    if (e.key && !e.shift) {

        switch (e.key) {
            case 'up':                  
                this.selectel.getPrevious().addClass('active');
                if(this.selectel) this.selectel.removeClass('active');
                this.selectel = this.selectel.getPrevious();
                e.stop(); 
            return;

            case 'down':
                var test = this.selectel.getNext();
                console.log(typeof(test));

                if(this.selectel.getNext() != null) {  // not working

                    this.selectel.getNext().addClass('active');
                    if(this.selectel) this.selectel.removeClass('active');
                    this.selectel = this.selectel.getNext();
                }
                e.stop(); 
            return;

        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you get on typeof test output? is `console.log(this.selectel)` the element you expect it to be? is or even, is `this` pointing to the class instance or to the window object (depends on how the `this.fireEvent("command")` is bound - `this.fireEvent("command", this);` ?)

btw, this is not the error but: you don't need to evaluate if selector has come null directly, you can just do `if (this.selectel.getNext()) { ... }` which will eval as true if defined and false if null anyway. 

element.getNext() accepts a selector as well, so you could do `.getNext("div.inactive")`

Comment: this is the class instance. like i said above console.log(this.selectel) outputs [null]. I also tried with (this.selectel.getNext()) { ... } but i get not null but [null], an null object i cannot handle.

Comment: if `this.selectel` outputs null then this scope is not bound to the class instance. if it can't find the element, it certainly won't find the element next to it. you need to show me the class itself where the `fireEvent("command")` takes place (probably on a keyup or something). **p.s. you never said this.selectel is null but this.selectel.getNext() - but it's a chain that starts from and replies upon the original element being a proper reference to a dom object**

Comment: I guess you dont get it. this.selectel outputs [null] NOT null on the last li element. Going up and down the autocomplete results works fine. So parsing the UL Element works. It's only the last LI Element which causes trouble. There is when i get [null] for the next (non existing) LI Element.

Comment: ah fair enough. does `if (!this.selectEl.getNext()) { e.stop(); return;} .. code here that uses the getNext (cache it)` not work? if null it will eval as false. if all fails, post on jsfiddle and i will have a look...

Comment: It is not null but [null] which is not false.

Comment: it returns an array? this is peculiar... any chance you can create a http://www.jsfiddle.net test case for me

Answer (score 0):

your are calling getNext() twice.

replace these lines:

```
if(this.selectel.getNext() != null) {  // not working
   this.selectel.getNext().addClass('active');
   if(this.selectel) this.selectel.removeClass('active');
   this.selectel = this.selectel.getNext();
}
```

with:

```
if(el = this.selectel.getNext() != null) {  // not working
   el.addClass('active');
   if(this.selectel) this.selectel.removeClass('active');
   this.selectel = el;
}
```

Comment: Thats not working. i tried this without success:
var test = this.selectel.getNext();
    if(test != null) {
        test.addClass('active');
        if(this.selectel) this.selectel.removeClass('active');
        this.selectel = this.selectel.getNext();
}

Comment: all he suggests is caching the selector into el so you don't call it twice. needs var el = though else it becomes window.el which is not desirable.

Comment: I allready stored it into test (see above). But if(test != null) { ... is not getting null but [null] which is not false.